# Scala: How do I calculate the variance of a Seq[Double] using flatMap and Options?

Tags: scala

I am trying to solve a "simple" exercise in Scala. I have this function:

```
def mean(xs: Seq[Double]): Option[Double] =
if (xs.isEmpty) None
else Some(xs.sum / xs.length)
```

This is the text of the exercise:

> EXERCISE 2: Implement the variance function (if the mean is m ,
>   variance is the mean of math.pow(x - m, 2) , see definition ) in terms
>   of mean and flatMap .

I was thinking something like

```
val xs = List(1.3,2.1,3.2)
val m = mean(xs)
xs flatMap(x=> math.pow(x-m,2)).mean //error!
```

What is the right way to solve? If possible I would like also a small theoretical explanation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I wouldn't call this simple.

`map` on `Option[A]` takes a function `A => B` and returns an `Option[B]` which is a `Some` if the original was a `Some`, and `None` otherwise.  So `Some(2).map(_+2)` gives `Some(4)`, but `None[Int].map(_+2)` gives None.

`flatMap` is much the same, but it takes a function `A => Option[B]` and still returns an `Option[B]`.  If the original is `None` or the given function results in `None`, the result is `None` otherwise it's a `Some[B]`.

You don't want to `flatMap` over the list, you want to `flatMap` the option.  I'll give you a hint, it starts with:

```
mean(xs).flatMap(m => ...
```

After that arrow, `m` is a `Double`, not an `Option[Double]`.

---

Edit:

Alright, fine, since we're getting all downvotey and not being helpful, here's the full answer:

```
def variance(xs: Seq[Double]): Option[Double] = {
  mean(xs).flatMap(m => mean(xs.map(x => Math.pow(x-m, 2))))
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot the solution was much more complex than expected

Comment: You have to normalize it with the length of the input vector.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Putnam's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/28773242/revisions) gives some good pointers. I found it easier to understand this problem by breaking it up into smaller chunks.

```
scala> val xs = List(1.3,2.1,3.2)
xs: List[Double] = List(1.3, 2.1, 3.2)

scala> def mean(xs: Seq[Double]): Option[Double] = {
     | if (xs.isEmpty) None
     | else Some(xs.sum / xs.length)
     | }
mean: (xs: Seq[Double])Option[Double]
```

Calculate the deviation of each element from the mean of the sequence:

```
scala> mean(xs).map(m => xs.map(x => x-m))
res0: Option[List[Double]] = Some(List(-0.9000000000000001, -0.10000000000000009, 1.0))
```

`map` works because if `mean(xs)` is `Some`, `x => x-m` is evaluated. Otherwise it isn't and we get `None`.

Now calculate the squared deviation from the mean of the sequence:

```
scala> mean(xs).map(m => xs.map(x => math.pow(x-m, 2)))
res1: Option[List[Double]] = Some(List(0.8100000000000003, 0.010000000000000018, 1.0))
```

Then calculate the mean of that:

```
scala> mean(xs).map(m => mean(xs.map(x => math.pow(x-m, 2))))
res2: Option[Option[Double]] = Some(Some(0.6066666666666668))
```

But here we have an `Option` that contains an `Option`, so we use `flatMap` to get the value of the first `Some`. So the solution with the desired return type `Option[Double]` is:

```
scala> mean(xs).flatMap(m => mean(xs.map(x => math.pow(x-m, 2))))
res3: Option[Double] = Some(0.6066666666666668)
```